# NDSolve for solving delay equations with impulses

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a system of delay equations (DDE), that in some periods of time receive an impulse to one of its equations.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

The equation (2) is the one receiving impulses of size $10^6$. So, I'm trying to use `NDsolve` of solve numerically this system with initial conditions $T=6*10^4$ ,$C_i=2*10^6$,$C_a=0$,$D=0$,$F_\beta = 0$  for $t<=0$.

```
dTdelay = 
  rt T[t] Log[K/T[t]] - 
   at Ca[t] T[t] (((1 - atb) etb)/(etb + Fb[t]) + atb);
dCadelay = 
  ra Exp[-μci τ] Ci[t - τ] (Den[t - τ]/(
     Den[t - τ] + θd)) + 
   re Exp[-μca τ] Den[t - τ] (Ca[t - τ]/(
     Ca[t - τ] + θa)) - μca Ca[t];
dCidelay = -ra Exp[-μci τ] Ci[t - τ] (Den[t - τ]/(
     Den[t - τ] + θd)) - μci Ci[t];
dFbdelay = rtb T[t] - Fb[t] μb;
dDendelay = (-Den[t] μd);

param3 = {rt -> 0.001060289, K -> 1*10^11, at -> 6*^-11, ht -> 5*10^8,
    atb -> 0.69, etb -> 10^4, 
   re -> 6500, θd -> 10, θa -> 212, 
   ra -> 61, μca -> 0.01925, μci -> 0.007, 
   rtb -> 5.57*10^-6, μb -> 2.7, μd -> 0.009625};

dose = 10^6; τ = 265; tf = 1000;

teraphy2 = {WhenEvent[t == 168, Den[t] -> Den[t] + dose], 
   WhenEvent[t == 336, Den[t] -> Den[t] + dose], 
   WhenEvent[t == 504, Den[t] -> Den[t] + dose]};

sys = {T'[t] == dTdelay , Ca'[t] == dCadelay , Ci'[t] == dCidelay , 
   Fb'[t] == dFbdelay , Den'[t] == dDendelay , 
   T[t /; t <= 0] ==  6*^4, Ca[t /; t <= 0] ==  0, 
   Ci[t /; t <= 0] ==  2*^6, Fb[t /; t <= 0] ==  0, 
   Den[t /; t <= 0] ==  0};
```

Also i'm using WhenEvent to add the impulses at $t=168$ , $t=336$ , $t=504$.But `NDsolve` returns:

```
sol = NDSolve[
   Join[sys, teraphy2] /. param3, {T, Ca, Ci, Fb, Den}, {t, 0, tf}];

NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 432.9999999999877`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

I know that the problems happen in $t=433$ when the delayed equations (3) and (4) start receiving the 
impulsed from $D[t-\tau]$ at $t=168$. Then suddenly (3) and (4) change. And that seems to cause problems to `NDsolve`.

NDsolve works fine until $t=433$ :

```
    sol = NDSolve[
   Join[sys, 
     teraphy2, {WhenEvent[t == τ + 168, "StopIntegration"]} ] /. 
    param3, {T, Ca, Ci, Fb, Den}, {t, 0, tf}];
    Plot[Evaluate[{T[t], Ca[t], Ci[t], Fb[t], Den[t]} /. First[sol]], {t, 
      0, 433}, PlotRange -> All, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[{"T", "Ca", "Ci", "Fβ", "D"}, Above],
     Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Apply[Point, {{168, 0}} ]} ]
```

Which returns:

[image]

I'm trying to overcome the problem integrating until $t=433$, save the data as interpolated functions. Using `NDsolve` to restart integrating 
 at  $t=433$ but im still receiving.

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 432.9999999999877`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

Any help of suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NDSolve` will solve it if you decrease the `AccuracyGoal` but I am worried that your model may have some underlying problems.  First, a solution up to `t=500`:

```
tf = 500;
sol = NDSolve[Join[sys, teraphy2] /. param3, {T, Ca, Ci, Fb, Den}, {t, 0, tf},
  AccuracyGoal -> 5];
Plot[Evaluate[{T[t], Ca[t], Ci[t], Fb[t], Den[t]} /. First[sol]], {t, 0, tf},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"T", "Ca", "Ci", "Fβ", "D"},
  Above]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That negative `Ci` worries me.  Could be a numerical problem, but I think it might not be.  Take a look at the first term in eqn 4, `dCidelay`.  `Ci` decreases due to `Ci` `τ` time ago.  Since `Ci` is decreasing with time, there is nothing preventing `Ci` from becoming negative, as it does.  The following graphs support this argument:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Ci[t], Ci[t - τ]} /. First[sol]], {t, 400, tf}, PlotRange -> {0, All}]
Plot[ra Exp[-μci τ] Ci[t - τ] (Den[t - τ]/(Den[t - τ] + θd)) /.
  param3 /. sol[[1]], {t, 400, tf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you let the next pulse hit, all hell breaks loose:

```
tf = 710;
sol = NDSolve[Join[sys, teraphy2] /. param3, {T, Ca, Ci, Fb, Den}, {t, 0, tf}, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
Plot[Evaluate[{T[t], Ca[t], Ci[t], Fb[t], Den[t]} /. First[sol]], {t, 400, tf},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"T", "Ca", "Ci", "Fβ", "D"}, Above]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, my guess is it's more of a model problem than an `NDSolve` problem.